# No enclosing instance of the type DonationsActivity is accessible

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm extremely new to all of this coding stuff, and I've gotten pretty far on my own, but I can't seem to figure out this error. All help is appreciated.

"No enclosing instance of the type DonationsActivity is accessible in scope"

```
package com.ganttbros.shadowui;

import org.donations.DonationsActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class DonateActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_donate);

final Button donate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.donatebutton);
    donate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(DonationsActivity.this, DonationsActivity.class));
                }
            });
        }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.donate, menu);
    return true;
  }

 }
```

I should tell you that I am attempting to implement this library: https://github.com/dschuermann/android-donations-lib#readme
I have set up the button, but I just need to get it to launch the "DonationsActivity" when pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
startActivity(new Intent(DonateActivity.this, DonationsActivity.class));
```

**OR**

```
startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), DonationsActivity.class));
```

instead of

```
startActivity(new Intent(DonationsActivity.this, DonationsActivity.class));
```

for starting `DonationsActivity` Activity from `DonateActivity` Activity

Comment: thanks a ton. That fixed it. Take it easy! I would upvote you if I could. :P

Comment: What does (new Intent(v.getContext(), DonationsActivity.class)) do? Why "v.getContext()"?

Comment: @Nate : `View.getContext()` also return u current View Context which u can also use for Starting Activity

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(DonationsActivity.this, DonationsActivity.class));
```

to:

```
startActivity(new Intent(DonateActivity.this, DonationsActivity.class));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I would upvote you if I had the power to.

Comment: @Nate: That is all right. I am glad to have helped even without an upvote. ;-)