# Unable to create Intent with 2 parameters (X.class,Y.class)

Tags: android, android-intent

My layout has a button which I added a listener to. See code below:

```
Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(ParseStarterProjectActivity.this,UserInfoActivity.this);
        i.putExtra("dummy", dummyData);
        startActivityForResult(i,0);
    }
});
```

However, I received the following error messages:

1. The constructor Intent(ParseStarterProjectActivity, UserInfoActivity) is undefined
2. No enclosing instance of the type UserInfoActivity is accessible in scope.

I've made sure that the UserInfoActivity activity was added to the Android Manifest and it's in the same package as ParseStarterProjectActivity. This Stackoverflow question ([No enclosing instance of the type DonationsActivity is accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995597/no-enclosing-instance-of-the-type-donationsactivity-is-accessible)) describes my issue but the accepted answer didn't work for me. I wouldn't want that method because I need to stuff items in my intent before starting. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line

```
Intent i = new Intent(ParseStarterProjectActivity.this,UserInfoActivity.this);
```

to this

```
Intent i = new Intent(ParseStarterProjectActivity.this,UserInfoActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentClassName.this,CallingClassName.class);
i.putExtra("dummy",dummyData);
startActivityForResult(i,0);
```

understand what is the purpose of intent and how to use it from

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: Thank you! I'd been staring at the screen way too long.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(ParseStarterProjectActivity.this,UserInfoActivity.class);
    Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // you can initialize intent to outside of this event
            i.putExtra("dummy", dummyData);
            startActivityForResult(i,0);
        }
    });
```

`this` points to current class. so change the extension of `UserInfoActivity`.